# PostgreSQL connects through django but not wsgi, library has no ciphers

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to a database on another server in my django app, but I'm getting the error (in my apache error log):

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not create SSL context:
>   library has no ciphers

I can use manage.py shell and connect to this database:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mobilesurvey user=django password=xxx host=dugong-api-rmove.rsginc.com port=5432")
```

What can I do to get this working through django?

Comment: Do you know if the db requires ssl?

Comment: Yes, the pg_hba.conf file has the connection type as hostssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue thread](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1569) had a number of workarounds, but what worked for me was building psycopg2 from source (doing a `pip install -r requirements.txt`, where my requirements.txt file included: `psycopg2==2.7.4 --no-binary :all:`).